# Apply grayscale effect on image

Tags: c#, image, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, writeablebitmap

I am trying to apply a filter on an image.

**XAML :**

```
<Image Name="imageForEditing" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
       Width="400"  Height="400" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

This is the method I use for getting the image from a picture library:

```
public async void pickPhoto()
    {
        FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
        openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");

        StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite);

                imageForEditing.Source = image;

                wbImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)imageForEditing.ActualWidth,(int) imageForEditing.ActualHeight);
                wbImage.SetSource(stream);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Greska : " + e.Message);
                msg.ShowAsync();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            (Application.Current as App).isEditorNext = false;
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplashScreen));
        }
    }
```

- `wbImage` is a global variable

So, when I try to apply the effect on the image I get an exception saying that my value should not be null.

Here is the code for the grayscale effect (I don't even know if it is working, I haven't been able to try it yet)

```
private WriteableBitmap GrayScale(WriteableBitmap modifiedImage)
    {
        try
        {
            int r = 0, a = 0, i = 0;
            int h = modifiedImage.PixelHeight;
            int w = modifiedImage.PixelWidth;

            using (Stream stream = modifiedImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
            {
                byte[] StreamBuffer = new byte[modifiedImage.PixelBuffer.Length];
                byte[] tempbuffer = new byte[64000];
                stream.Seek(0, 0);
                stream.Read(StreamBuffer, 0, StreamBuffer.Length);

                for (i = 0; i < StreamBuffer.Length - 4; i = i + 4)
                {
                    var a1 = StreamBuffer[i + 3];
                    var r1 = StreamBuffer[i + 2];
                    var g1 = StreamBuffer[i + 1];
                    var b1 = StreamBuffer[i + 0];

                    a = 0xff;
                    r = (byte)((0.311 * r1) + (0.486 * g1) + (0.213 * b1));
                    StreamBuffer[i + 3] = (byte)a;
                    StreamBuffer[i + 2] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
                    StreamBuffer[i + 1] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
                    StreamBuffer[i + 0] = (byte)(r > 255 ? 255 : (r < 0 ? 0 : r));
                }
                stream.Seek(0, 0);
                stream.Write(StreamBuffer, 0, StreamBuffer.Length);
                modifiedImage.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             var exceptionMessageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Exception : " + ex.Message);
            exceptionMessageDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
```

The exception is thrown here :

```
Stream stream = modifiedImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream();
```

What am I doing wrong? I've been searching for answers for more than 5 hours. Nothing seems to help.

I checked if `modifiedImage` is null, but it seems to be fine. Here is how the method is called and where I set `imageForEditing.Source`.

```
        wbImage = GrayScale(wbImage);
        imageForEditing.Source = wbImage;
```

Comment: Did you check `modifiedImage` using the debugger? What about `modifiedImage.PixelBuffer`?

Comment: Yes, they seem to be fine.The problem is this line:
`modifiedImage.PixelBuffer.AsStream()` 
I am unable to convert the buffer to `System.IO.Stream` -

Comment: Yes, if the problem is that line it means one of the variables on that line is null... what is in PixelBuffer?

Comment: It's an `IBuffer` object, capacity and length are all set,it is not null, if that is what you meant.

Comment: Can you strip out the try...catch, supply the precise exception, and check which line it is on, and check if the call stack suggests it is inside a library method rather that yours, if `PixelBuffer` is indeed not `null`, then your code should not be throwing a `NullReferenceException` on that line. *note that the using statement doesn't care if stream ends up being null*

Comment: Make sure you are awaiting the call to pickPhoto() before calling GrayScale(). Otherwise the image may not be loaded yet and PixelBuffer could be null.